# How to solve this NDSolve problem in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, ode

I found a confusing problem in solving ODE problems with NDSolve in Mathematica, the code is as follows:
I have tried `'Clear[Derivative]'` and restart the kernel but these methods don't work.
CODE:

```
   Clear[Derivative];
    ClearSystemCache;
    r = 0.3; a = 3; delta = 0.45; M0 = 0.975; T = 20;
    u[t] = 0.5*l[t]*delta*M[t];
    eql1 = M'[t] == r*M[t] Log[1/M[t]] - u[t]*delta*M[t];
    eql2 = l'[t] == -2 *a *M[t] - l[t]* r *Log[1/M[t]] + l[t]*r - 
        l[t]*u[t]*delta;
    condition = {M[0] == M0, l[T] == 0};
    sol = NDSolve[Flatten@{{eql1, eql2}, condition}, {M, l}, {t, 0, 20}]
The result is as follows:
    Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
    Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. \[Infinity] encountered.
    Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
    Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. \[Infinity] encountered.
    Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
    General::stop: Further output of Power::infy will be suppressed during this calculation.
    Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
    General::stop: Further output of Infinity::indet will be suppressed during this calculation.
    NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXacU.png)

I can't figure out why there be "`non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0`", there shouldn't be the non-numerical value at t==0, the whole M[t] should be >0 when t<=20. I have spent a lot of time on this problem and still could not find an answer, please help me.
Best regards!

Comment: You sure this question is not better suited on [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: You're right, I didn't know there be a Mathematica stack exchange :) thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The reason these code doesn't work is that mathematica can not solve ODES with singular points and bounded condition. I use python write Ronge-Kutta method to solve the problem and it works. Life is short, I use python :>